# Why is the YouTube JavaScript API OnPlayerStateChange event handler no longer working? Is this a catastrophic bug?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

As of 2013-06-13 at approximately 2 AM, my streaming video service [FMGEM.com](http://fmgem.com) can no longer auto-advance playlists. I was just notified of this as it has affected a production system that has not been changed in over one week.

I put a debugger in the `OnPlayerStateChange` event handler and to my shock & chagrin it no longer fires.

As a sanity check I looked at a competitors website, [tubalr.com](http://tubalr.com) and they have the exact same problem.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-api-onstatechange-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a temporary problem. It was reported and solved with a temporary fix, here:

[YouTube Iframe API - OnStateChange suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078989/youtube-iframe-api-onstatechange-suddenly-not-working)

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. "Temporary" is not subjective when your traffic falls by 100% instantly!